# How do I return multiple key-value pairs in Scala using Spark's map transformation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I'm new to Scala and Spark. I'm trying to return multiple key-value pairs during the map transformation. My input data is a simple CSV file.

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

My Scala script looks like the following.

```
class Key(_i:Integer, _j:Integer) {
 def i = _i
 def j = _j
}
class Val(_x:Double, _y:Double) {
 def x = _x
 def y = _y
}
val arr = "1,2,3".split(",")
for(i <- 0 until arr.length) {
 val x = arr(i).toDouble
 for(j <- 0 until arr.length) {
  val y = arr(j).toDouble
  val k = new Key(i, j)
  val v = new Val(x, y)
  //note that i want to return the tuples, (k, v)
 }
}
```

I want to be able to use the for loop and data structures above to return multiple tuples (k, v). Something similar to the code below.

```
val file = sc.textFile("/path/to/test.csv")
file.map(line => {
 val arr = line.split(",")
 for(i <- 0 until arr.length) {
  val x = arr(i).toDouble
  for(j <- (i+1) until arr.length) {
   val y = arr(j).toDouble
   val k = new Index(i,j)
   val v = new Val(x,y)
   (k,v)
  }
 }
}).collect //reduceByKey is not there, reduce is there, but not what i want
```

When I copy/paste the code above into the lambda expression (and run on the Scala REPL shell) I get the following error:

```
error: illegal start of simple expression
val arr = line.split(",")
^
```

I realize also that I am still stuck in imperative/procedural style programming thinking, so please bear with me (and a newbie at Scala/Spark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting the brackets after the arrow. You can only omit them if it is a simple expression (one expression).

```
file.map(line => {
    //multiple lines of code here
})
```

**Full answer after edits:**

```
case class Index(i:Integer, j:Integer)
case class Val(x:Double, y:Double)

val data = sc.parallelize(List("1,2,3", "4,5,6", "7,8,9"))
data.flatMap(line=>{
val arr = line.split(",")
 val doubleSeq = for(i <- 0 until arr.length) yield {
  val x = arr(i).toDouble
  for(j <- (i+1) until arr.length) yield {
   val y = arr(j).toDouble
   val k = Index(i,j)
   val v = Val(x,y)
   (k,v)
  }
 }
 doubleSeq.flatten
})
```

There were a multitude of problems actually:

- Notice that I changed your classes to be case classes as they are serializable. Otherwise, you will need to implement `Serializable`
- I changed `map` to `flatMap`, as well as `flatten`ed your array as one `flatMap` would still leave you with an inner array. Now, the combination of the two will yield you your `RDD[(Index, Val)]`, which can now be implicitly used with `reduceByKey`
- I turned your `for` loop into a `for` comprehension by using `yield`. You were getting a final type of `Unit` because the return type of a `for` loop is `Unit`

Comment: Your suggestion helped. Now that error goes away. But when I add the return statement, return (k,v), I get the following: error: return outside method definition.

Comment: I did not see that...DO NOT return in scala, the final statement is the return value. That will fix it I would think

Comment: Do you know how I can check to see if the lambda function is correct? When I do file.map(line => {...}).collect, all I see is Array[Unit] = Array((),(),...()). What I want to do next is reduce all the values by the same key. However, autocomplete (hitting tab) indicates that reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit]. I'm still stuck in the MapReduce state of mind.

Comment: I posted the code that works now with your help. Note that in the example above, I use collect to try and inspect what's actually in that RDD. Meanwhile, I'm reading this article http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-translate-from-mapreduce-to-apache-spark/ and it seems to suggest that the map function in Scala/Spark has 1 input and 1 output, and because of what I want to do, I might have to use the flatMap function.

Comment: Yes, flatMap seems the right thing. Not exactly the same as your code, but this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472603/bloating-a-dataset-with-spark-scala/29473305#comment47111526_29473305 also uses flatMap to generate more than one output row from each input row. It may point you in the right direction?

Comment: @JaneWayne I just posted a full answer...you actually had a multitude of problems. And, the code can probably be cleaned up even further, but should work for your purposes :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `RDD.flatMap` and `yield` a list from the `for` loop:

```
val file = sc.textFile("/path/to/test.csv")
file.flatMap { line =>
  val arr = line.split(",")
  for {
    i <- 0 until arr.length
    j <- (i + 1) until arr.length
  } yield {
    val x = arr(i).toDouble
    val y = arr(j).toDouble
    val k = new Index(i, j)
    val v = new Val(x, y)
    (k, v)
  }
}.collect
```

Comment: Scala `for` loops are magic. I've never found the documentation for them and at this point I'm afraid to ask.