# Bloating a dataset with spark & scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my requirement

Input

```
customer_id status  start_date  end_date
1   Y   20140101    20140105
2   Y   20140201    20140203
```

Output

```
customer_id status  date
1   Y   20140101
1   Y   20140102
1   Y   20140103
1   Y   20140104
1   Y   20140105
2   Y   20140201
2   Y   20140202
2   Y   20140202
```

I'm trying to achieve this with cartesian product in spark and it looks to very inefficient. My dataset is too huge. I'm looking for a better option.

Comment: SO you want a line per day between start and end, inclusive for each customer id. Is status always Y? If not, what should the output be for non-Y?

Comment: status can be 'N' as well..its either Y or N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your idea correctly you can do it this way:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("test")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  case class Input(customerId: Long, status: String, startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate)
  case class Output(customerId: Long, status: String, date: LocalDate)

  val input: RDD[Input] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Input(1, "Y", LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 5)),
    Input(2, "Y", LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 3))
  ))

  val result: RDD[Output] = input flatMap { input =>
    import input._
    val dates = Stream.iterate(startDate)(_.plusDays(1)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(endDate))
    dates.map(date => Output(customerId, status, date))
  }

  result.collect().foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
Output(1,Y,2014-01-01)
Output(1,Y,2014-01-02)
Output(1,Y,2014-01-03)
Output(1,Y,2014-01-04)
Output(1,Y,2014-01-05)
Output(2,Y,2014-01-01)
Output(2,Y,2014-01-02)
Output(2,Y,2014-01-03)
```

Comment: dates is going to be a   normal collection, though, not an RDD. So probably won't fit on any one node.

Comment: I don't think that dates collection can be bigger then 1 megabyte, so it should not be an issue

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the input flatMap, which should mean you end up with an RDD again.

Comment: unfortunately it gets stuck while reading the input dataset itself... In my case input is a textfile in S3...